# Could not print "hello" in Geany editor

Tags: c, gcc, cmd, gcc-warning, geany

I have installed geany and also have MinGW compiler. I am trying to print a simple "hello" but unable to do so. I have saved my file in the name of print.c.
The error that I am getting- .\print is not recognized as an internal or external command.
below I have attached the need:

[image: Image of code and cmd]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kegP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kegP.png)

Comment: The "Compiler" tab at the bottom of your screenshot shows that it's compiling the file `hi.c` into the output file `hi`, which is different from the names of the source files shown on the left panel, which seems odd. That said, this question contains too little information for us to help you.

Comment: @kotatsuyaki hello i have edited my image.If you could check this..

Comment: The mismatch of filename still persists. In the editor you have `hello.c`, but the compiler tried to compile another file named `hi.c`.

Comment: @kotatsuyaki i have fixed it. but still it says not recognized